# Permission Denied

Tags: android, react-native, voximplant

Hello so i have this android script in my app, but whenever i try to build it i get that permission denied, what should i do?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

yarn add react-native-geolocation-service
yarn add @voximplant/react-native-foreground-service

cd android/app

# AndroidManifest
cd src/main
cat <<EOF > /tmp/adalo-sed
/android.permission.INTERNET/a\\
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />\
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />\
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>\\
EOF

sed -i.bak "$(cat /tmp/adalo-sed)" AndroidManifest.xml

echo "configured Android settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you get the message "permission denied" when executing the script?

Does the script have the "execute" permission?
You can check that with `ls -l <your script>`.
If there is no "x", then you need to set the execute permission, eg. via `chmod +x <your script>`

Comment: @JimmyNoujaim if your problem was solved then please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark of the answer that solved it. Optionally you can also upvote useful responses.